# How to sum up a measure based on different levels in Power BI using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following table structure:

```
| Name 1 | Name 2 | Month  | Count 1 | Count 2 | SumCount |
|--------|--------|--------|---------|---------|----------|
| A      | E      | 1      | 5       | 3       | 8        |
| A      | E      | 2      | 1       | 6       | 7        |
| A      | F      | 3      | 3       | 4       | 7        |
```

Now I calculate the following with a DAX measure.

```
Measure = (sum(Table[Count 2] - sum(Table[Count 1])) * sum(Table[SumCount])
```

I can't use a column because then the formula is applied before excluding a layer (eg. month). Added to my table structure and excluded month it would look like that:

```
| Name 1 | Name 2 | Count 1 | Count 2 | SumCount | Measure |
|--------|--------|---------|---------|----------|---------|
| A      | E      | 6       | 9       | 15       | 45      |
| A      | F      | 3       | 4       | 7        | 7       |
```

I added a table to the view which only displays `Name 1`in which case the measure of course will sum up `Count 1`, `Count 2` and `SumCount` and applies the measure which leads to the following result:

```
| Name 1 | Measure |
|--------|---------|
| A      | 88      |
```

But the desired result should be

```
| Name 1 | Measure |
|--------|---------|
| A      | 52      |
```

which is the sum of `Measure`.

So basically I want to have the calculation on my base level `Measure = (sum(Table[Count 1] - sum(Table[Count 2])) * sum(Table[SumCount])` but when drilling up and grouping those names it should only perform a `sum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iterator function like `SUMX` is what you want here since you are trying to sum row by row rather than aggregating first.

```
Measure = SUMX ( Table, ( Table[Count 2] - Table[Count 1] ) * Table[SumCount] )
```

Any filters you have will be applied to the first argument, `Table`, and it will only sum the corresponding rows.

---

**Edit:**

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to aggregate over `Month` before taking the difference and product. One way to do this is by summarizing (excluding `Month`) before using `SUMX` like this:

```
Measure =
VAR Summary =
    SUMMARIZE (
        Table,
        Table[Name 1],
        Table[Name 2],
        "Count1Sum", SUM ( Table[Count 1] ),
        "Count2Sum", SUM ( Table[Count 2] ),
        "SumCountSum", SUM ( Table[SumCount] )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( Summary, ( [Count2Sum] - [Count1Sum] ) * [SumCountSum] )
```

Comment: That is pretty close to my requirement. Thanks! Is it possible for SUMX to somewhow "change the starting level". Because now the calculation is made on the base table (with month) but it should be made on the second level where month is excluded. So there should be a distinct filter or something for `Name 1` and `Name 2` in `SUMX()`. Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want measure in this case, rather you need new column,

Same formula but new column will give your desired result.

```
Column = ('Table (2)'[Count1]-'Table (2)'[Count2])*'Table (2)'[SumCount]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to stick with a measure because the calculation should not be done on the initial table. It should be done when I filter out the `Month` column. And all upcoming filters should only sum up that `Measure` column.
Please check my corrected answer.